# Presenting a new UIViewControler within a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UITabBarController with a NavigationBar. In the NavigationBar is a button which instantiate a new UIViewController with an UINavigationController: `self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)` and as i expected the view is presented over fullscreen.

So on, my question is: How can i present the new UIViewController without hiding/overlapping my Tabbar?

Comment: Can you try something like that : `self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)` ?

Comment: thank you, i've tried it but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you are setting the correct `modalPresentionStyle` on the view controller you're presenting. Perhaps `.CurrentContext` or `.OverCurrentContext`. For this to work you should also set `definesPresentationContext` to `true` on the `selectedViewController`. In your `UITabBarController` subclass:

```
nav.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
self.selectedViewController?.definesPresentationContext = true
self.selectedViewController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```